How to display the value of any key in alert notification email?
In Grafana alerts setup I have this Lucene query:
kubernetes.name: $customer AND x_Duration : * AND message : *

How can I make the contents of the "message" field to appear in the alert notification email?
I tried these steps:

Under Alerting's "Configure labels and notifications" section created a custom label with a key "message" and value {{ $values.A.Value }}

Under "Contact points" menu "Optional Email settings" section created this template:



But it doesn't work, the Values in the notification email are empty.

If that image of text can be added as text, please [edit] your question to do so. See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
